# php login function not return the true session id

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this function

```
function login_check($username, $password ){
global $mysqli;
$password = md5($password);

$sql = $mysqli->query("select a_id, a_email from admin where a_email='".$username."' and a_password='".$password."'")or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($num_rows == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $macke_session = $_SESSION['a_id'] = $row['a_id'];
    return $macke_session;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

in while loop I used this also .

```
 return $_SESSION['a_id'] = $row['a_id'];
```

and this

```
$_SESSION['a_id'] = $row['a_id'];
```

and this

```
if ($num_rows == 1){
return true;
}else{return false;}
```

it's work correctly !! but I have a problem
the problem is
win I logged any user in ,, it's always logged in  the user that have an id 1 !!!!

I tried all way to make another user log in but

> nothing happing ,, just the user that have an id number 1 is logged in, directly

I don't know how can I let the function chose the correct session id

please help 
thanks on advance :D

Comment: Does `@macke_session` return the correct ID?

Comment: this doesn't help you `or die(mysql_error())` this will `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))`. Turn error reporting on and set to display. Plus, I hope you're not intending on going live with your use of MD5. Make sure the session has been started also.

Comment: the session is starting and I got logged in but I always logged in as the first user in the data base ,,  and     win I use mysqli_error($mysqli) ,, I got this error     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\iman\include\func.php on line 22

Comment: what do you mean about **@macke_session**

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: More problems: `mysql_error` won't tell you anything if you're using `mysqli` as it's part of a different library. Security wise, MD5 for passwords is utterly useless, please **do not** use it. If you're determined to do it yourself, you need to be aware of [proper password hashing procedures](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing).

Comment: I'm not using md5 hash and I'm not using any hash now,,, I mean I delete md5 hash and the problem is still there ,,, I change MySQL_error  , I'm using mysqli now !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDITED

as you requested in the comment, here is a procedural login function that i created and tested for you, may not be perfect. you need to add security and bring changes according to your preference, and also never output debugging messages in release project, that is for just debugging purpose. best of luck. Hope i helped :). if it works i request you to mark this as answer, else comment whats not working.

my **test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//test case a_id = 1
$username="test1@gmail.com";
$password="testpassword";
//test case a_id = 2
//$username="test2@gmail.com";
//$password="test2password";
$dbserver="localhost";
$dbusername="dbuser";
$dbpassword="dbpasss";
$dbname="testdb";

//echo $_SESSION['attempt'];
if(isset($_SESSION['attempt'])&&$_SESSION['attempt']<5){    
$link = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
echo '<pre>';
login_check($username,$password,$link);
echo '</pre>';}else{echo "Debugging: Too many wrong attempts";
}

function login_check($username, $password,$link){
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Debugging:Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error);
        exit();
    }else
   {
    $password=md5($password);
    $query="SELECT * FROM `admin` where a_email='".$username."' AND a_password='".$password."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['attempt']=isset($_SESSION['attempt'])?$_SESSION['attempt']:0;
        $row['a_id']!=""?$_SESSION['a_id'] = $row['a_id']:$_SESSION['attempt']++;
        if($row['a_id']!="")
        {
            //user match
            $_SESSION['a_id'] = $row['a_id'];
            $_SESSION['attempt']=0;
            echo "Debugging::...<br>row id=".$row['a_id']."<br>";
            echo "Session id=".$_SESSION['a_id']."<br>";
            print_r($row);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //user doesn't match
            $_SESSION['attempt']++;
            echo "Debugging:Session attempt=".$_SESSION['attempt']."<br>";
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

my **test2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Password attempts".$_SESSION['attempt']."<br>";
echo "Session a_id=".$_SESSION['a_id']."<br>";
```

Comment: it's logged in successfully as always ,,, but the problem is still there ,,, **it's always return the session for user id number 1 ** and the other users is not taking a session ! ,,, is the problem with data base of where ?

Comment: check this and tell me if it doesn't work. the 1 might not be the result that come from database, it might be the return value of the query or result, indicating that its true(1).

Comment: the result that came from the data base is printed win I use print_r command and it's giving me the right user is but win the page is redirecting the user that have id number 1 is logged in and the user that want to logged in is take nothing !

Comment: do you mean print_r($macke_session) ??

Comment: yes ,,, win I print_r($macke_session); I got the right id that I have been but it in login form ,,, and the system tolling me you are logged in successfully ,,, and he return the user id 1 not 2 or 3 or ....etc

Comment: try it on a_email like this $macke_session = $_SESSION['a_id'] = $row['a_email']; instead of id for debugging, than it would be easy to identify the problem.what does it return?

Comment: I change it and I have the same problem :(( ,,, what is the problem ,, it was working with me !!!

Comment: Is it still 1?if so it means as I said its not a result, its the return value..did you change the code as I mentioned in the answer??are you using $macke_session or $_SESSION['a_id'] to call?use $_SESSION['a_id'].btw I dnt see you using those variables.include in the question..

Comment: I tried all possible ways and I got nothing ,,, it make login and the session is printing the correct data ,, but win the login form redirect ,, the user that have an id 1 is logged in ,,, I tried to delete all data from users table and I insert it again but this give me nothing ,,, so !!  ,,, look if you can build the function for me that will be cool ,, please if you can do it please help ,,, the columns in table 'users' is 'a_id , a_name, a_email , a_password' ,,, and thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: @HusamMEkhrawesh check the answer now :) Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

looool ,,, you will not believe this
my function is working correctly and your too 
I was logged in successfully every time but the problem in another function :((((

the function that make the problem is

```
function user_data(){
global $mysqli;

//$session_id = @$_SESSION['a_id'];

$args = func_get_args();
$fields = '`'.implode('`, `',$args).'`';

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT $fields FROM admin WHERE a_id='".isset($_SESSION['a_id'])."'")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$query_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
foreach($args as $field){
    $args[$field] = $query_result[$field];
}
return $args;}
```

this function is for fetching logged in users data !

I have been changed this line
to be like this

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT $fields FROM admin WHERE a_id='".$_SESSION['a_id']."'")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

it was like this

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT $fields FROM admin WHERE a_id='".isset($_SESSION['a_id'])."'")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

but the problem now is ,, I'm getting this

```
Notice: Undefined index: a_id
```

the **isset()** function is returned the first user in **database** every time
and I don't know why !

I tried to but it in variable and I got the same problem win I use 
**isset()** function

so ,, I have to rebuild **user_data()** function if that necessary

thank you verey much for your help ,, I'm shy

this Embarrasses me :((

I think if I changed the session name on all functions to **a_email** it will work correctly

**thank you very much again and that was so kind from you to helping me guys best regards for all**